# Context error in Adapter for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my Adapter for my RecyclerView I trying to text whenever text is clicked on each row but I am getting a context error. I'm a beginner programmer so I'm not sure what to do. Thanks in advance. Also I'm trying to create an app where in each row there is a messaging group chat that everyone can see and each user has the ability to add a row with whatever title they choose. If someone could help me with that, it would be awesome! And be very appreciated because I'm pretty novice. Thank you!

The error I'm getting takes place where I have my toast where it says context.

Adaper code:

```
package com.example.patri.index01;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Information> data= Collections.emptyList();

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;

}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Information current=data.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(current.title);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);

    holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item clicked at " +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView title;

    ImageView icon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        title= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);

        icon= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);

    }
}
}
```

Information class:

```
public class Information {

int iconId;

String title;

}
```

Comment: you didn't initialize `context` yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is getting because `context` is not accessible inside `onClick` method which is passed in `MyAdapter` class Constructor.

In `onClick` method use `v.getContext()` :

```
  Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Item clicked at " +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

OR

Declare `context` in `MyAdapter` class and initialize it in Constructor:

```
Context context;
public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
    this.context=context;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;

}
```

Comment: Do you know how I could have the whole row being clicked instead of just the text?

Comment: @PatrickJ.: make whole layout clickable instead of TextView then add `setOnClickListener` to layout

Comment: How would I do this using Information class? Do I have to define it or something? I'll add an edit @ρяσѕρєя K

Answer (score 0):

Change `Toast.makeText(context, "Item clicked at " +position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)` to `Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Item clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Can make it so when the whole row is clicked it displays the toast?

Comment: Yes. You have no variable context inside `onClick` callback, so you need to get it, view has it. So we writes 'v.getContext()'. Also you need to call `show()` to show your Toast, not just create it.